# Return object from _.map()

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, dictionary, underscore.js

So the `_.map()` function in underscore doesn't return an object, but it takes them. Is there any way for it to return the exact same object it takes?

```
var _ = require("underscore");

var cars = {
    "mom": {
        "miles": "6",
        "gas": "4"
    },
    "dad": {
        "miles": "6",
        "gas": "4"
    }
}

var regurgitate_cars = _.map(cars, function(value, key){
    return value;
});

/*
[ { miles: '6', gas: '4' }, { miles: '6', gas: '4' } ]
*/

var regurgitate_cars = _.map(cars, function(value, key){
    var transfer = {};
    transfer[key] = value;
    return transfer;
});

/*
[ { mom: { miles: '6', gas: '4' } },
  { dad: { miles: '6', gas: '4' } } ]
*/
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Shallow/deep copy an object?

Comment: See mapValues for underscore https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/issues/220

Comment: _.reduce() should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`_.object()`](http://underscorejs.org/#object) to turn it back into an object.

```
var regurgitate_cars = _.object(
    _.map(cars, function(value, key){
        return [key, value];
    })
);
```

As for doing that directly with `_.map`, you'd have to rewrite map to do it.

Comment: You would need to `return [key, value]` for this to work ...?

Comment: @McGarnagle, good call. You are right, and the post has been updated. And it looks much more succinct.

Answer (score 7):

`_.map()` will always return an array, but you can get the behavior with [`_.reduce()`](http://underscorejs.org/#reduce):

```
var regurgitateCars = _.reduce(cars, function(memo, value, key) {
    memo[key] = value;
    return memo;
}, cars);
```

Note that this will modify and return the original object, if you wanted a copy you can provide an empty object as the third argument, which will be used as the `memo` argument on the first call of the anonymous function:

```
var regurgitateCars = _.reduce(cars, function(memo, value, key) {
    memo[key] = value;
    return memo;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 1):

`map` returns an `array` so there's no way you could get it to return the original object with out writing your own. See [documentation](http://underscorejs.org/#map):

> Produces a new array of values by mapping each value in list through a
>   transformation function (iterator). If the native map method exists,
>   it will be used instead. If list is a JavaScript object, iterator's
>   arguments will be (value, key, list).

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to return a object with the current implementation of map. [It's been suggested](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/issues/220) that the library add a `.mapValues()` function which would do what you like. Here's how you would add it to your code:

```
_.mixin({
    mapValues: function (input, mapper) {
        return _.reduce(input, function (obj, v, k) {
            obj[k] = mapper(v, k, input);
        }, {});
    }
});
```

Now you can use mapValues to return a new object:

```
var regurgitate_cars = _.mapValues(cars, function(value, key){
    return value;
});
```